# Get the next 10 records without using LIMIT x,x

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

I'm trying to get the next 10 records without using this structure

```
SELECT * FROM records LIMIT 3,10
```

I found another method that gives the same result

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE id > 3 LIMIT 10
```

but I want to go based on a targeted value of a column call html_id not based on the id column.

For example getting the next 10 records after this record note *ignore the yellow borderline*

[image: photo 1]

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE html_id='i1481988552' /*The next 10 records after i1481988552 but how??*/
```

As a result it should look like something like this

[image: photo 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the ID of the record with the `html_id` that you want, then use that to compare with the IDs of the other records.

```
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM records WHERE html_id = 'i1481988552')
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 10
```

This can also be written as a self-join:

```
SELECT r1.*
FROM records AS r1
JOIN records AS r2 ON r1.id > r2.id
WHERE r2.html_id = 'i1481988552'
ORDER BY r1.id
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Wow this is what I was looking for thanks Barmar sorry for the late response I got busy.